# What's the Debian equivalent of Ubuntu Core/Base images?

Tags: debian, root-filesystem, container

For Ubuntu I use the Core/Base images as available here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/

These 'images' are just base rootfs tarballs which can be used with for example [rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt/). More information on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core

Does Debian ship similar type of release images? I can't seem to find these on https://www.debian.org/distrib/. Debian does publish Docker-specific images on the Docker hub, but not the "upstream" rootfs, apparently. Or am I missing something? :)

Also accepted as an answer; how to create such a core/base image?/ `debootstrap` something something I guess?

Comment: Debootstrap may be what you are looking for see https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap or one of its relatives; I remember last time I did this I used a relative of debootstrap (If I remember correct). One of these tools is probably what the ubuntu team used to create their tar-balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian does indeed not ship such images, because it's trivial to create them with debootstrap:

```
debootstrap <suite> <target directory> <mirror>
```

Downloads packages for *suite* from *mirror*, and installs them into *target directory*. Once that's finished, create a tarball of the target directory, and you're done. Note: not 100% sure of the ordering of the arguments. The man page is pretty clear, though :-)

Comment: Thanks. Found it here also: [coreos/rkt/scripts/acbuild-rkt-builder.sh](https://github.com/coreos/rkt/blob/022d8772b8c9f3cca844845a7cf4b678cedaa845/scripts/acbuild-rkt-builder.sh#L36). So, with the same logic, I'm not sure why it would be necessary for Ubuntu to ship these images, but okay. Will try this out in rkt later.

Answer (score 0):

A better and more alternative debootstrap is [debuerreotype: reproducible, snapshot-based Debian rootfs builder](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype) to create the images.

- Creates tarballs of the rootfs.
- Reproducible builds.

It's also the base of the official Docker images.